# Android, java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: Failed resolution of: Lorg/slf4j/LoggerFactory

Tags: android-activity

I am trying to make a **webDav** client on **Android** using sardine library. I am using Android Studio as IDE. So I added `sardine-5.0.1.jar` in my libs folder and compile files(`sardine-5.0.1.jar`) in `build.gradle`. The project compiles well but when I execute it, I have the error:

> java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: Failed resolution of:
>   Lorg/slf4j/LoggerFactory.

I just have a single activity.

```
import android.app.Activity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import com.github.sardine.Sardine;
import com.github.sardine.SardineFactory;

public class MainActivity extends Activity {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        Sardine s = SardineFactory.begin();//This line is the problem
    }

}
```

I tried to add some slf4j.jar files like explained in other tutorials, but it did not help. I'm really struggling with that for a moment and maybe i should take another library for webDav Client.

Comment: Is the .jar file in the lib folder of your project?

Comment: sardine-5.0.1.jar is in my libs folder, i deleted the slf4j.jar because it didn't help.